# java lookbehind for split by greedy quantifiers expressions

Tags: java, regex, greedy, quantifiers

I wrote the following expression to split a string after every x word (3 for instance) followed by a space. My problem is that I need to keep the entire content. But I cannot find a way to use look behind etc to accomplish this in Java.

Anyone has experience with that?

```
String text = "Hello my name is Tom and i love playing football";
String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){" + ngramm_length + "}";
System.out.println(regex);
String[] ngramms = text.split(regex);
```

result are 4 tokens but only the last one still contains the content, I would like to get:

> `1: Hello my name 2: is Tom and 3: i love playing 4: football`

Look into the match information box in the link JAVA Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
    int length = 3; //2
    String dynamic_length = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {       
        dynamic_length += i;

        if (i + 1 < length) {
            dynamic_length += ",";         
        }
    }

    final String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){" + length + "}|([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){" + dynamic_length + "}";
    final String string = "Hello my name is Tom and i love playing football\n\n";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        ++count;
        System.out.println("match:" + count + " " + matcher.group(0));
    }
```

it is not dynamic because it is only working for length of 2 and 3. That's my problem with it or do I miss something?

for x > 1 i can use:

```
final String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){" + length + "}|([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){1," + (length - 1) + "}";
```

for x = 1 i can use:

```
final String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){" + length + "}|([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){1}";
```

or just splitting by space.

Thanks to Maverick_Mrt !!!

Comment: If you want to gather results which can be matched by regex then use `Matcher#find` rather than `split` which treats regex as representation of place on which it should split string.

Comment: Maybe could also use more compact one like [`"(?:\\w+\\W*){1,3}"`](http://fiddle.re/u3e0ua) with find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\s){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\s){1,2}
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lMSpe7/4)

Look into the match information box in the link
JAVA Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){3}|([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\\s){1,2}";
    final String string = "Hello my name is Tom and i love playing football\n\n";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        ++count;
        System.out.println("match:" + count + " " + matcher.group(0));
    }
```

As per your comment:

if you want **n** block per match then you do it, make sure n>0

```
([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\s){n}|([a-zA-Z0-9öÖäÄüÜß]+\s){1,n-1}


Sample output

    match:1 Hello my name 
    match:2 is Tom and 
    match:3 i love playing 
    match:4 football
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, but you regex is not working in java, i still get 4 tokens but only the last one contains football. Moreover this regex isn't dynamic anymore.

Comment: I have added code segment for you, isn't it what you want ?

Comment: its fine but not dynamic:

Comment: what is not dynamic here ? clear your question out firstly

Comment: Didn't you want to make 3 words per block in your question ?

Comment: dynamic means that you can execute the regex with x for the quantifier, so for every nonnegative integer

Comment: thats great :) it is working for n > 1, thank you :)

Comment: feel free to accept this as answer then , to make it work for n==1 you can just split it by space. you dont need regex or remove every thing from | in the regex